# Terminology for joining two curves

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

What is the correct and/or established terminology for the join of two curves?

To be more specific, given two curves on a manifold $M$, $c_1:[a,b]\rightarrow M$ and $c_2:[b,c]\rightarrow M$ with $c_1(b)=c_2(b)$, form $c=[a,c]\rightarrow M$ where

\begin{align*}
c(t)=\begin{cases}
c_1(t) & \textrm{ if } t\in[a,b],\\
c_2(t) & \textrm{ if } t\in[b,c].
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then $c$ is union/join/splice of $c_1$ and $c_2$? Also, is there a notation for this operation, like $c=c_1\cup c_2$?

Comment: You could call it the product or concatenation of the curves. In algebraic topology, you'd see this curve denoted by $c_1 \ast c_2$

Comment: Thanks, product sounds nice. Is there a notation for the case of more than two curves, like $*_{i=1}^nc_i$?

Comment: You can surely denote it like that if you want to, I think Hatcher might do that in his topology book somewhere. Remember, notation and terminology is what you make of it :)

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make sure I don't use introduce something new if there already exists an established terminology/notation.

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are varying conventions on parameterization; e.g. the common choice to parameterize all curves on $[0,1]$ and write $$(\gamma_1*\gamma_2)(t)=\begin{cases}\gamma_1(2t) & 0\le t\le 1/2\\\gamma_2(2t-1) & 1/2<t<1\end{cases}$$Which convention you use is largely a matter of taste and convenience, but it's often best to specify.